# linq beginner, foreach statement without declaration?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm just reading some LINQ for dummies stuff and I got a question. Here is the code:

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create an array as a data source.
    String[] QueryString = { “One”, “Two”, “Three”, “Four”, “Five” };

    // Define the query.
    var ThisQuery = from StringValue in QueryString 
                    where StringValue.Length > 3
                    select StringValue + “\r\n”;

    // Display the result.
    foreach (var ThisValue in ThisQuery)
        txtResult.Text = txtResult.Text + ThisValue;
}
```

What is txtResult, will it work without a declaration?

Comment: Probably a control on the UI.

Comment: @Pleun. What're you talking about?

Comment: Wait... What is the question?

Comment: @gdoron What the f is? Not the best language for a newbie

Comment: What kind of application are your working on, winform or webapplication

Comment: @OndroTadanai: thx for editing. reversed my -1

Comment: @Pleun. But there isn't an f word here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

txtresult is the value of Name Property of used TextBox control in this code. You need to add a TextBox in your application and assign it Name property value 'txtresult' for this code to work.

Comment: I dont think he is that advanced yet my friend:)

Comment: In that case, I endorse your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Open Visual Studio > New Project > Windows Application

Drag a textbox control onto the form design surface.

Press F4, in the properties window set the Name property of the textbox to `txtResult`

Drag a button control onto the form design surface.

Peess F4, in the properties window set the Name property of the button to `btnTest`

Double click the button and it will take you to the buttons click event in code.

Paste in the above code and Press F11 to start debugging.

Answer (score 1):

txtResult is a textbox control. There must be another reference to it elsewhere in the example.

Answer (score 0):

It will give you error if txtresult is not on the form or in your class. Add it on the form/class or define a string variable to hold the results.

```
 foreach (var ThisValue in ThisQuery)
     txtResult.Text = txtResult.Text + ThisValue;
```